# exec /app/backendApp: no such file or directory in docker container

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I have a microservices base architecture but the container deploy successfully but its not started.

Below is the dockerfile.

```
FROM alpine:latest 

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY backendApp /app

CMD [ "/app/backendApp" ]
```

And below is the `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '3'

services:

  backend-service:
    build:
      context: ./backend-service
      dockerfile: backend-service.dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
    environment:
      DSN: "host=postgres port=5432 user=postgres password=password dbname=postcreation sslmode=disable timezone=UTC connect_timeout=5"
```

And below is the log of the docker container.

[image]

**EDIT**

I have tried the below docker file but it gives another error.

```
FROM golang:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY backendApp .

CMD [ "/app/backendApp" ]
```

Error
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is one rectification in the `backend-service.dockerfile`, `RUN mkdir /app` is not required, the line `WORKDIR /app` will create `app` directory if it doesn't exists.

Also, after `WORKDIR /app` command gets executed it will change to the newly created directory so, `COPY backendApp /app` can also be written as `COPY backendApp .`

`COPY backendApp /app` is also fine.

Now coming to the `no such file or directory` error, the `alpine` docker image is very minimalist Linux image.
`alpine` Linux image doesn't comes with standard runtime libraries needed by your `backendApp` executable, you need to find out the runtime dependencies and add/install into your `alpine` Linux image using `backend-service.dockerfile`.

Refer the example below to get a bit more of understanding:
This is the file structure of the directory

```
Dockers$ tree
.
├── backend-service
│   ├── backendApp
│   ├── backendApp.c
│   └── backend-service.dockerfile
└── docker-compose.yml

2 directories, 4 files
```

As you can see there is a `backendApp.c` file, with just a simple `Hello World!` print statement in a `while(1)` loop and `backendApp` is the compiled binary.

The contents of respective `backend-service.dockerfile` is shown below:

```
FROM alpine:latest 

WORKDIR /app
COPY backendApp .
CMD [ "/app/backendApp" ]
```

The `docker-compose.yml` is exactly same as yours, now after running `docker-compose build` I get the output image:

```
docker images
REPOSITORY                TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
dockers-backend-service   latest    bbd272015851   22 minutes ago   7.07MB
```

And if I run it, I get the exact same error as yours

```
docker run dockers-backend-service
exec /app/backendApp: no such file or directory
```

Now here the problem is that the `backendApp` is a C program which needs `libc6` library which is not part of `alpine` Linux image and that's why the error.

To resolve this I just have to add `RUN apk add libc6-compat` in `backend-service.dockerfile` and re-build the image and it will resolve the runtime dependency of `backendApp` binary

```
$ docker run dockers-backend-service
Hello Docker Compose!!
```

I hope this answers your Question!

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav for the detailed explanation. I understand it now. but I am looking for it for golang linux.  I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056387/how-to-install-go-in-alpine-linux but it's not working. Can you please help me with it?

Comment: Hi @GirishBhutiya, I tried running a simple go program binary in alpine linux and it is working fine with `libc6-compat`. You can try the same approach I mentioned in the answer, you just need to compile the go program before hand

Comment: Here is the latest dockerfile. https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/37888858?key=981f409949f6427b57ad5ef504acdd35 and here are new errors. - https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/37888868?key=38bd6e7db5c5cf3e89c25fee455fc0e9  I have tried to search for new errors on google but nothing works.

Comment: This is eligible for a new question, perhaps you can post more details along with your go lang program code